# backbone fetch always gives error callback in IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js, fetch

I have a collection in backbone as follows:

```
define([
    "jquery","backbone",

    "models/homeTile"
],

    function($, Backbone, Model) {
        'use strict';

        // Creates a new Backbone Collection class object
        var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

            // Tells the Backbone Collection that all of it's models will be of type Model (listed up top as a dependency)
            model: Model,

            url: 'http://easyuniv.com/API/hometiles',

            comparator: function(tile) {
                return 1.0 / tile.get('userCount');
            }

        });

        // Returns the Model class
        return Collection;
    }

);
```

When I call fetch on the object in FF or chrome it runs perfectly fine. However, in IE it always enters the error callback of fetch.

I have looked in the network tab of F12 dev tools and it is not showing a network call for the collection.

When I have this as my error callback:

```
error: function(data, response) {
    console.log(response.responseText);
}
```

It just prints `LOG: undefined`

any ideas on what this could be?

Comment: I'd step into the fetch code of backbone. It's not too wild as it eventually calls the ajax function of jquery/zepto with the path. Is it a cross-domain call? (And just to be sure, you started tracing in IE on the Network tab, right?)

Comment: yeah, I see other requests fine in IE, and yes it is cross domain. Well, in the sense that its being run locally and the server is online